# No USART communication using hal_Driver

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, hal, usart

I am using a custom devBoard with a single STM32L071 chip. Using debug mode (System Workbench), I can see the TDR register of USART2, and the data I want to transmit is there, but there is no signal coming from the pins on the board.
There is no hardware issue, I had the board checked.

I found the GPIO configuration online, and the USART configuration is what I need.

My main function:

```
HAL_Init();
GPIO_Config();
Configure_USART();

char message[] = { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x55 };
HAL_UART_Transmit(&g_meterUart, (uint8_t*)message, sizeof(message), 0xFFFF);
```

GPIO configure

```
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE()
;
GPIO_InitTypeDef USART_GPIO_InitStruct;

USART_GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
USART_GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
USART_GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_7;
USART_GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
USART_GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &USART_GPIO_InitStruct);

USART_GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
USART_GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &USART_GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Configuring USART

```
__USART2_CLK_ENABLE();
g_meterUart.Instance = USART2;
g_meterUart.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
g_meterUart.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;   
g_meterUart.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
g_meterUart.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
g_meterUart.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
g_meterUart.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
g_meterUart.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;

if (HAL_UART_DeInit(&g_meterUart) != HAL_OK) {
}
if (HAL_UART_Init(&g_meterUart) != HAL_OK) {
};
```

Comment: 'I found the GPIO configuration online':(   Refer to the processor user manual.  Triple-check everything against the user manual.  Power up, pin select, pull up/downs, UART config etc.  Isolate the tx pin from external hardware while monitoring.  Check for any errata for the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple suspicious issues I found with a quick review of the [STM32L071 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l071cb.pdf).  According to Table 16, page 49:

1. PA2 is USART2_TX but you have configured GPIO_PIN_2 for GPIO_MODE_INPUT.  Do you have the direction of PA2 and PA3 reversed?
2. The USART2 functions of PA2 and PA3 are selected with Alternate Function 4 but you have specified LL_GPIO_AF_7.

Comment: Upon further review, the mode GPIO_MODE_AF_PP for PA3 seems correct.  But I think the PA2 mode should also be GPIO_MODE_AF_PP rather than GPIO_MODE_INPUT.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The problem was the Alternate function seting